# Is One-Hot Encoding required for using PyTorch's Cross Entropy Loss Function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, multilabel-classification

For example, if I want to solve the MNIST classification problem, we have 10 output classes. With PyTorch, I would like to use the `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` function. Do I have to format the targets so that they are one-hot encoded or can I simply use their class labels that come with the dataset?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`nn.CrossEntropyLoss` expects integer labels.  What it does internally is that it doesn't end up one-hot encoding the class label at all, but uses the label to index into the output probability vector to calculate the loss should you decide to use this class as the final label. This small but important detail makes computing the loss easier and is the equivalent operation to performing one-hot encoding, measuring the output loss per output neuron as every value in the output layer would be zero with the exception of the neuron indexed at the target class.  Therefore, there's no need to one-hot encode your data if you have the labels already provided.

The documentation has some more insight on this: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html.  In the documentation you'll see `targets` which serves as part of the input parameters.  These are your labels and they are described as:

[image: Targets]

This clearly shows how the input should be shaped and what is expected.  If you in fact wanted to one-hot encode your data, you would need to use `torch.nn.functional.one_hot`. To best replicate what the cross entropy loss is doing under the hood, you'd also need `nn.functional.log_softmax` as the final output and you'd have to additionally write your own loss layer since none of the PyTorch layers use log softmax inputs and one-hot encoded targets. However, `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` combines both of these operations together and is preferred if your outputs are simply class labels so there is no need to do the conversion.

Comment: So you mean that if I use CE loss. the target input is the label value. no need to use one-hot encoding. right?

Comment: @LoaySharaky Yes.  To elucidate this, suppose in your batch you have an input tensor of `N x D` with `N` being the batch size and `D` being the dimensionality of a a single example.  The targets should simply be a 1D tensor of size `N` where the values can go from `0` to `C - 1` with `C` being the total number of classes.  However, the shape of the **output layer** for your predicted values should be of size `N x C`.  Therefore, the loss function will take the labels in the targets as indices and directly access the values in the output layer tensor to calculate the loss.

Comment: Not sure whether this changed but `nn.NLLLoss` does NOT accept one-hot encoded vectors as target as claimed in this comment.

Comment: @Aydo yes this has now changed. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the `ImageLoader` to load the dataset from folders itself then PyTorch will automatically label them for you. All you have to do is structure the folder like this:

```
|
|__train
|   |
|   |__1
|   |_ 2
|   |_ 3
|   .
|   .
|   .
|   |_10
|
|__test
    |
    |__1
    |_ 2
    |_ 3
    .
    .
    .
    |_10
```

Each class should have a separate folder for them.   If you are loading data from DataFrame you can use below code to encode them:

```
one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target)
```

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about how to load data or how to convert labels to one hot encoded form. They specifically ask about whether CE loss requires labels one hot encoded or not.

Comment: @akshayk07 exactly

Comment: The OP wants to know if labels can be provided to the Cross Entropy Loss function in PyTorch without having to one-hot encode.  Presumably they have the labels ready to go and want to know if these can be directly plugged into the function.  The OP doesn't want to know how to one-hot encode so this doesn't really answer the question.